# Flyway migration status `outOfOrder`?

Tags: flyway

I have recently enabled `outOfOrder` in my Flyway config to solve some merge conflicts.
 The problem is when I run `migrate` all my scripts get executed and in status it shows `OutOfOrder`.

I want to know does `OutOfOrder` mean success state ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is a successfully applied migration.

See [MigrationState#OUT_OF_ORDER](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/7925112a1041d7763d722a4d36cbbb39277e7b5c/flyway-core/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/core/api/MigrationState.java#L88) for a bit more detail.

```
    /**
     * <p>This migration succeeded.</p>
     * <p>
     * This migration succeeded, but it was applied out of order.
     * Rerunning the entire migration history might produce different results!
     * </p>
     */
    OUT_OF_ORDER("OutOrdr", true, true, false)

   /**
     * Creates a new MigrationState.
     *
     * @param displayName The name suitable for display to the end-user.
     * @param resolved   Flag indicating if this migration is available on the classpath or not.
     * @param applied     Flag indicating if this migration has been applied or not.
     * @param failed      Flag indicating if this migration has failed when it was applied or not.
     */
    MigrationState(String displayName, boolean resolved, boolean applied, boolean failed) {
```